# X-Ray Node Scraper not finding class on Soundcloud

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

Hey Guys I built a very basic scraper to pull information off of soundcloud. I am using x-ray and it doesnt seem to be able to find the tags where the music infomation is stored. Any thoughts? Code is below

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var xray = new Xray(); 

xray('https://soundcloud.com/search?q=Burning%20Man', '.searchItem',

[{
    Hai: 'div:nth-child(1) @aria-label'


}]
).write('results.json')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search results are loaded through AJAX and aren't part of the initial page contents (they get added to the page dynamically). It doesn't look like `x-ray` is capable of handling such a setup.

Instead of trying to parse the page, you could also use the search API directly:

```
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/search?q=Burning%20Man
```

More documentation [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I originally wanted to scrape track ids for use with the api. I know the id can be found in the share this track section but I wanted to be able to dynamically pull a bunch at a time